# Issue in opening multiple tabs via chrome.tabs.create

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension, createprocess

I am encountering an issue in opening multiple tabs using chrome.tabs.create method. I am trying to open some 9 tabs in loop using chrome.tabs.create, though the number of tabs that open up get limited to 4 only. It looks like the loop ends up pretty early before the tabs get actually created.

Assuming that I am able to get all the links to be opened in links_array variable. How should I create a JavaScript Synchronous callback that allows every tab to be opened.

I might be wrong in guessing the exact problem, but will be glad to know, if I haven't found something missing in this puzzle.

> **Edit**: Chrome Extensions have been restricted to open not more than 3
>   or 4 tabs in a single click(as found through many other questions),
>   but there has been no such official statement from the Chrome
>   Extension Devs, regarding this situation.

Comment: Where have you found this information about that restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add listener for the [chrome.tabs.onCreated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated) event in the background.js and in the callback function call create method for the next tab? But beware infinite loop.

Comment: that's a viable option but, I have tried using Recursion to create tabs, but that too doesn't help.. I'm wondering that may be clicking on a link forces the chrome extension to terminate. I might be terribly wrong, but I am not able to get as to why things are not working.. also, I tried using Web Workers, but have found that chrome object is not available in the web_worker js.